# Highcharts addPoint animation

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using `addPoint` with `animation=true` to update a series in Highcharts. When the update frequency is higher than the animation duration the whole time series is showing some strange animation.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t797ewpw/13/

Related issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7926

I tried to find a workaround (maybe using some callback to keep the state of a running animation and delay calls to `addPoint`). But it seems there is no such callback (only for initial animation).

Are there any other workarounds for this issue?

Comment: What do you think about using the lower value of the `chart.animation.duration`, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xtyj2ub8/?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, thanks for your suggestion. This is what I have configured and it helps normally. But there are cases where the updates are triggered with higher frequency than 400ms (I cannot control this because it comes from a web socket).

Comment: I tried to change the `animation.duration` time dynamically to value smaller than the frequency of the addPoint and here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9yjdrq3x/ I am afraid that with the current animation implementation it is best what can be done without the core changes. You can reopen this ticket and GitHub and ask core developers, maybe some of them will have a better idea.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianWędzel. I will update the ticket.